# Laravel each() method

Tags: laravel, foreach, each

I am trying to understand why the following is always returning false:

```
public function checkDate($transactions)
{
    $start = Carbon::now()->subMonth();
    $end = Carbon::now();

    $transactions->each(function ($transaction) use ($start, $end) {

        $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $transaction->date);

        if ($date->between($start, $end))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });

    return false;
}
```

When I remove both the `return false`, then `null` is being displayed.

When I use a regular `foreach`, it works:

```
$start = Carbon::now()->subMonth();
$end = Carbon::now();

foreach($transactions as $transaction)
    {
        $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $transaction->date);

        if($date->between($start, $end))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

The thing what I don't understand is, when I do the following:

```
public function checkDate($transactions)
{
    $start = Carbon::now()->subMonth();
    $end = Carbon::now();

    $transactions->each(function ($transaction) use ($start, $end) {

        $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $transaction->date);

        if ($date->between($start, $end))
        {
            dd('test');
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });

    return false;
}
```

Then `"test"` is being displayed.

Can someone explain as to why this is happening, since I don't understand it.

Comment: Because the only return statement in this function is the last line, which returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `each` method doesn't stop iterating when `true` is returned. It does stop, however, when `false` is returned.

> If you would like to stop iterating through the items, you may return false from your callback:

[Collection Methods - each()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-each)

Your method only returns `false` also.

If you are trying to verify all transactions fall with a date range, then use the [every](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-every) method:

```
// returns true if all transactions date are between start and end, otherwise returns false.
return $transactions->every(function ($transaction) use ($start, $end) {
    $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $transaction->date);

    return $date->between($start, $end);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am basically only trying to check wether a transaction was made for a subscription between a certain date period, and if that is the case, true needs to be returned, if not, false. The foreach works, but I was trying to learn about the `each()` method, and I have learned a bit, thanks :)